# Display feature or label that contain certain word in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, print-composer, expression

I have a column `"name"` and on it is contains several row like

- Candra Hotel
- Ibis Hotel
- Season park
- Central park Mall
- Boom Mall
- Johor market

I want to display names that only contain word `"mall"` on it, what is the formula for that filtering in QGIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Case sensitive

Use this expression to evaluate if the field `"name"` contains the string `Mall` (does not find `mall` etc.):

`"name" LIKE '%Mall%'` or alternatively `strpos("name",'Mall')>0`

#### Ignore case of first character

Be aware that the above solution is case sensitive, finding `Mall`, but not `mall`. To include both versions, use:

`regexp_match("name",('M|mall'))>0`

#### Ignore case completey

To find variants like Mall, mall, MALL, MAll, maLL, MaLl etc., use:

`lower("name") LIKE '%mall%'` or `"name" ILIKE '%mall%'` or `regexp_match("name",'(?i:mall)')` - [see here for this last syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58818125/13651925)

#### QGIS expression functions reference

See the help of the functions used here:

- [`LIKE`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#like)
- [`ILIKE`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#ilike)
- [`strpos()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#strpos)
- [`regexp_match()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-matches)
- [`lower()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#lower)